# Firebase-Tools : firestore:delete error in Emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'am trying to use the recursive delete from firebase-tools inside a firebase cloud function. And I'm testing this with the emulator.

But at the moment, I am not very successful.

**It seems that the CLI is using the Firestore REST API. Is it available with the emulator?**

My function is this:

```
import * as firebaseTools from 'firebase-tools';
import { db } from './admin';

const DEBUG = true;

export async function deleteUserData(userId) {
  if (DEBUG) console.log('Delete user data', userId);

  await firebaseTools.firestore.delete(`users/${userId}/contacts/`, {
    project: db._projectId,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true, // auto-confirmation
  });

  if (DEBUG) console.log('User data deleted', userId);
}
```

Here is the log from the emulator:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "deleteUserData"
>  Delete user data 4AiyOyCnAPSrKhc1Ycf6nVDqLoD2
>  i  You have set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=tornado.local:3344, this command will execute against the firestore emulator running at that address.
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myapp-dev-f7v4:testIamPermissions"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  External network resource requested!
   - URL: "http://tornado.local:3344/v1beta1/projects/myapp-dev-f7v4/databases/(default)/documents/users/4AiyOyCnAPSrKhc1Ycf6nVDqLoD2:runQuery"
 - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>  Error with Delete FirebaseError: Failed to delete documents FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 403, 
>  Null value error. for 'list' @ L11
>      at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/pitouli/Documents/GIT/myapp-app/functions/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/firestore/delete.js:251:28)
>      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
>      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
>    name: 'FirebaseError',
>    children: [],
>    context: undefined,
>    exit: 1,
>    message: 'Failed to delete documents FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 403, \n' +
>      "Null value error. for 'list' @ L11",
>    original: undefined,
>    status: 500
>  }
i  functions: Finished "deleteUserData" in ~1s
```

Thanks for your help!

---

EDIT 1 : it seems the REST API should work with the emulator since it's given as example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#clear_your_database_between_tests

I note that in my case the request is made on the `v1beta1` endpoint when it's made on the `v1` endpoint in the doc example.

---

EDIT 2 : following @sam recommendation, I tested with non restrictive rules, and it works. But as far as I know, Cloud Functions are supposed to ignore the rules (#gangsta)

Here are my "normal" rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow create, read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

And here are those I used for the test:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Firebaser here] this should work within the emulator but it looks like you found a bug.  Does this work if you temporarily adjust your security rules to allow all deletes?

Comment: Hello @SamStern: you got a point :) with "open rules", it works. I edit my post to provides my rules. I believe they are corrects (very permissive, but they should be enough to prevent a user from accessing data of another user) ; if you confirm it, I will open a bug ticket

Comment: thanks!  I submitted a fix here (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2211) and it will be included in the next CLI release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed by the firebase team in [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2211).